# symfony validar archivo gpx (variante xml)

Tags: xml, symfony2

estoy tratando de filtrar la subida de un archivo a traves del formulario. El tipo de archivo que trabajo es .gpx (posiciones gps). Internamente se trata de un archivo xml, pero su mimetype es application/gpx+xml.

he puesto lo siguiente en el archivo validation.yml sobre la entidad route:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Route:
    properties:
        pointsFile:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - File:
                mimeTypes: "application/gpx, application/gpx+xml"
                disallowEmptyMessage: "Required"
                uploadErrorMessage: The file could not be uploaded
```

La propiedad que representa el archivo es **pointsFile**.

Cuando cargo un archivo .gpx, me muestra el mensaje de error:

```
El tipo mime del archivo no es válido ("application/xml"). Los tipos mime válidos son "application/gpx, application/gpx+xml".
```

El formato .gpx es en realidad un xml. Por lo que veo al subir un archivo lo identifica como xml y me lanza el error. Lo que quiero lograr es subir unicamente archivos .gpx correctos, y si es otro archivo que de error (tanto sean xml como no)

Alguien sabe como se puede forzar este tipo? O debo hacer un constraint propio para evaluar el contenido primero???

Comment: A todas luces, el mime type es el que es... Podrías controlar que sea un `application/xml` y con una constraint de tipo `Callback` verificar, por ejemplo, la extensión. O más exhaustivamente, que el DOM del documento contenga un nodo específico.

Comment: Gracias Muriano. Estoy preparando un constraint que evalue precisamente el contenido y que me encuentre el nodo trk|trkseg.  He comprobado que hay dos funciones en el constraint sobre el value: getMimeType y getClientMimeType. En el caso del gpx devuelve siempre application/xml, pero en otros me devuelven otros valores... Mañana pongo la solucion.

Answer (score 1):

Al final he hecho lo que comenta @Muriano escribiendo un Constraint, siguiendo el manual de symfony. Dejo aquí mi solución, aunque preferiría algo más "symfony", como decía al principio, utilizando el mimetype...

El constraint:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class ConstraintsGPXFile extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Invalid file content';
}
```

el validator:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

class ConstraintsGPXFileValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if(!empty($value)) {
            $crawler = new Crawler();
            $crawler->addXmlContent(file_get_contents($value));

            try {
                $crawler->filter('default|trkpt');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                    ->addViolation();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que hago es revisar el contenido del archivo que se sube. El !empty es por si estas editando  (no es obligatorio subir el archivo).  Utilizo el componente domcrawler de symfony, y si no encuentro un nodo 'default|trkpt' agrego un addViolation().

Comment: Me alegra que haya funcionado. No olvides marcar esta respuesta como correcta para poder dar por cerrada la pregunta.